# Get view from url

Tags: django, url

How do I get and call the view function assosiated with a given url?

I have a view performing some work and then (if all went well) passes on the request to another view (one of several possible) and returns the response rendered by this view.

Pseudocode:

```
class View1(view):
    def dispatch():
        do_common_tasks()
        if (foo):
            return render("template1")
        elif (bar):
            return url_to_view2.render()
        else:
            return url_to_view3.render()
```

Is this a valid approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) function to resolve a url path to a view. You would then call the function with the `request` object.

```
func, args, kwargs = resolve('/some/path/')
return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that `resolve` may raise [`Resolver404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/#django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404).